# PHP Warning: mysqli_query(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:967)

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Running into a strange error running a MySQL query with php:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:967) in /ours/scripts/update-trending.php on line 97
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): EOF packet 1 bytes shorter than expected in /ours/scripts/update-trending.php on line 97
```

The query is simple and works fine when run by itself:

```
mysql> select ifnull(count(nid),0) from likes where nid=18578;
+----------------------+
| ifnull(count(nid),0) |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

The error appears during a for loop which cycles through nid values (1-19000). It works on 98% of the queries but it sometimes randomly fails with the above error. This is all happening on one mysqli connection, so it's not an authentication issue.

Actual code being used (within the for loop):

```
$qLikesSQL='select ifnull(count(nid),0) from likes where nid=' . $thisNID;

if ($qLikesResulter=mysqli_query($link,$qLikesSQL)) { 
    if ($qLikesRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qLikesResulter))
    { 
        $qLikes=$qLikesRow['ifnull(count(nid),0)']; 
    }
    mysqli_free_result($qLikesResulter); 
} else echo "MySQL query failed:  $qLikesSQL\n";
```

PHP Version:

```
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

MySQL Version:

```
AWS RDS Instance - Aurora MySQL 5.7.12
```

MySQL error logs being generated:

```
2018-03-27T13:27:52.576966Z 7276977 [Note] Aborted connection 7276977 to db: '***snip***' user: '***snip***' host: '***snip***' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

UPDATE:  I moved the database from the RDS Aurora MySQL (5.7.12) instance to an RDS MySQL (5.7.16) instance and the problem vanished. So this is likely something specific to Aurora.

Comment: _Just a small point_ You would make your life easier if you did `$qLikesSQL='select ifnull(count(nid),0) as nid_count from likes where nid=' . $thisNID;` and then could code `$qLikes=$qLikesRow['nid_count'];` Doesnt that look so much more readable?

Comment: Unlikely, but it may even solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, but no that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What sql engine are you using? are the columns indexed?

Comment: InnoDB. Yes the columns are indexed.

Comment: Think this is one of those mysql misleading error message. maybe it has to do with php.

Comment: I just posted an update -- switching this from RDS Aurora MySQL (5.7.12) instance to an RDS MySQL (5.7.16) instance solved the problem. So this is likely something specific to Aurora.